# Is SD Express more energy efficient than M2 NVMe?

Tags: ssd, storage, sd-card, hardware-rec, nvme

As laptop storage, for example, what would be more energy efficient, the new SD Express class cards or M2 NVMes?

Comment: efficiency is a concept that must take into consideration you performance specifications. it is likely that SD Express will use less electricity, but whether that is actually efficient for your usecases is another question entirely. a rock uses less electricity than an solar-powered calculator, but it can't calculate square roots.

Comment: Good point. I'm looking to add extra file storage to a laptop that takes MicroSD cards (the 2022 Samsung galaxy book2 pro 360). It will be used mostly to store a Zotero library and miscellaneous downloads I will be accessing and writing to regularly, such as documents , video, etc. Old SD cards seem a little slow for the price to me (90MB/s max). But if they are energy efficient for this use case I may opt for them instead of a second nvme. Or is there maybe something else that can fit into the nvme slot, perhaps a less expensive form of storage?

Comment: Wait a second, is it true than an SSD generally takes more power than an HDD? If so, is there any hope to use an HDD in an M2 nvme slot?

Comment: I've not looked it up, but I am fairly certain that SSDs use less electricity than HDDs. HDDs have to spin after all. I do not believe that you will find an HDD that can be installed on a m.2 slot, but also keep in mind based on ahesk01's answer, Any m.2 slot will provide the 3.5-5.0 watts, so any compatible device will either have that draw, or will use additional power cables from the PSU. I don;t think there are any such devices, but who knows

Answer (score 1):

M.2s require 3.5 to 5.0 watts of power, SD Express may use up to 1.8. So SD Express would be more efficient.

References:
https://www.sdcard.org/pdf/SD_Express_microSD_Express_BestChoice_WhitePaper20200515.pdf

[https://ssdsphere.com/ssd-power-consumption-comparison/#:~:text=Normally%2C%20you%20will%20see%20most,consume%20more%20than%202%20Watts](https://ssdsphere.com/ssd-power-consumption-comparison/#:%7E:text=Normally%2C%20you%20will%20see%20most,consume%20more%20than%202%20Watts).